# checking input length by getElementById is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function checkLength(input) {
  var element = document.getElementById('t').value;
  if(document.calculator.t.value.length == 10) {
    alert("ivalid length - 10 characters only!");
  }
  if(element.value.length > 10) {
    alert("ivalid length - 10 characters only!");
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="calculator">
  <input type="text" maxlength="10" name="answer" id="t" onkeyup="isAllowedSymbol(this);checkLength(this); " placeholder="Enter data" >
  <br />
  <input type="button" value=" 1 " onclick="calculator.answer.value += '1'" />
  <input type="button" value=" 2 " onclick="calculator.answer.value += '2'" />
  <input type="button" value=" 3 " onclick="calculator.answer.value += '3'" />
  <input type="button" value=" + " onclick="calculator.answer.value += '+'" />
  <input type="button" value=" exp " onclick="calculator.answer.value = Math.exp(calculator.answer.value);" />
  <br />
  <input type="button" value=" 4 " onclick="calculator.answer.value += '4'" />
  <input type="button" value=" 5 " onclick="calculator.answer.value += '5'" />
  <input type="button" value=" 6 " onclick="calculator.answer.value += '6'" />
  <input type="button" value=" - " onclick="calculator.answer.value += '-'" />
  <input type="button" value=" ln "  onclick="calculator.answer.value = Math.log(calculator.answer.value);" /> 
  <br />
  <input type="button" value=" 7 " onclick="calculator.answer.value += '7'" />
  <input type="button" value=" 8 " onclick="calculator.answer.value += '8'" />
  <input type="button" value=" 9 " onclick="calculator.answer.value += '9'" />
  <input type="button" value=" &#215; " onclick="calculator.answer.value += '*'" />
  <input type="button" value=" &#8730; " onclick="sqrt(calculator.answer.value)" />
  <br />
  <input type="button" value=" C " onclick="calculator.answer.value = ''" />
  <input type="button" value=" 0 " onclick="calculator.answer.value += '0'" />
  <input type="button" value=" = " onclick="calculator.answer.value = eval(calculator.answer.value)" />
  <input type="button" value=" &#247; " onclick="div(calculator.answer.value)"/>
  <input type="button" value=" x&#178; " onclick="sqr(calculator.answer.value)" />
  <br />
  <input type="button" value=" cos " onclick="calculator.answer.value = Math.cos(calculator.answer.value);" /> 
  <input type="button" value=" sin " onclick="calculator.answer.value = Math.sin(calculator.answer.value);" />
  <input type="button" value=" tan " onclick="calculator.answer.value = Math.tan(calculator.answer.value);" />
  <input type="button" value=" . " onclick=" "; />
  <input type="button" value=" &larr; " onclick="backspace(calculator.answer.value);"; />
  <p align=right>&#8226; &#169;</p>
</form>
```

Making my first calculator and I have a problem. Numbers entered by keyboard are checking (not bigger than 10), but those entered by buttons aren't... what is my problem? what I'm doing wrong? Maybe it is something with my `maxlength="10"`?

```
<input type="text" maxlength="10" name="answer" id="t" onkeyup="checkLength(this); " placeholder="Enter data" > <br>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are checking the length on the `onkeyup` event, which is fired when you type in the box. Accordingly, when you click on buttons, it's not.

One way to fix it would be to check this on the `onchange` event instead.

---

**Update:**

Also, for that fix to work as intended, you should manually trigger the `onchange` event since changing the `value` property does not dispatch it.

**JS:**

```
calculator.answer.value += '0';
calculator.answer.onchange();
```

Another, better way to do it would be:

**JS:**

```
if ("createEvent" in document) {
    var evt = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
    evt.initEvent('change', false, true);
    calculator.answer.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
else
    calculator.answer.fireEvent('onchange');
```

As the handler becomes more complex, it would probably be easier for you to create a generic handler for your buttons instead of inline commands.

Comment: Changing the `value` property doe not dispatch a `change` event.

Comment: @Oriol Thanks, I did not consider that. Will update.

Answer (score 1):

You say that values entered by keyboard are getting checked, but those entered with buttons aren't. The thing is you're binding the function to the event `onkeyup` which only occurs after key is pressed and the released inside the input, you should bind your function to the event `onchange`